# mat-tab-group is not a known element in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9

I am using Angular 9 with Angular Material 9.2.4.

I am trying to use the **mat-tab-group** in my component.html, but I keep getting the error

```
'mat-tab-group' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-tab-group' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-tab-group' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.ng(0)
```

I have installed Angular material using the following command

```
ng add @angular/material
```

My package.json is as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.0",
   
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.0",
    
   
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.7.2",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.47",
    "angular-archwizard": "^5.0.0",
    "angular-google-charts": "^1.1.4",
    }
```

I have imported the {MatTabsModule} in my module.ts

```
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs'

...
..
@NgModule({
declarations: [
...
..],
imports: [
 ....
MatTabsModule,
....]
..
..
export class PagesModule {}
```

Still when I use

```
<mat-tab-group></mat-tab-group>
```

I get the error mentioned in the top.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you demonstrate the problem through the Stackblitz?

Comment: 1) Ctrl + C 2) npm install --save @angular/cdk @angular/material 3) npm start

Answer (score 2):

You have not provided the name of your component and only a snippet of your PagesModule. Maybe your compoent is missing from your module-declarations.

Make sure to add your component to your declarations as well...

```
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs'
import {MyComponentThatThrowsTheError} from '<path/to/your/component>/MyComponentThatThrowsTheError.component>'
...
..
@NgModule({
declarations: [
MyComponentThatThrowsTheError
..],
imports: [
 ....
MatTabsModule,
....]
..
..
export class PagesModule {}
```